# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError while installing tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to follow along with the AI tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFr2WgN9_xE

but at 11:56 when he runs the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joshua/PycharmProjects/ tensorEnv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I tried re-installing tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow`, but I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Joshu
a\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37
\\site-packages\\tensorboard_plugin_wit\\_vendor\\tensorflow_serving\\sources\\storage_path\\__pycache__\\file_syste
m_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-37.pyc'
```

does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: This looks like the exact same error joshuachen1122 had. He posted something about it on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28893, see if there's an answer there.

Comment: @MichealChen thanks! it worked when I typed `pip install tensorflow==1.15.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I installed an older version of tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow==1.15.2`. Credit to @Micheal Chen for showing me a link to a similar issue